# How to check if forward slash / is present in the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
 if (preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $input,$oper)){
     $oprator = $oper[0];
 }
```

Here is my code. I can get plus, minus, multiply but not the divide one character. How can I update this preg_match to find if string contain divide?

For example if my string is 8/2 so oprator variable should get /

Comment: escape it `\/` , or use delimiter , for example : `#`

Comment: Try this one `/[\/\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/` You should add `/` and escape it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape it as follows :

```
if (preg_match('/[\/\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', '5/8',$oper)){
    //            ^^
    $oprator = $oper[0];
    echo $oprator;
}
```

live example : https://3v4l.org/HtN3N

or you may also use another [delimiter from this list](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

Answer (score 0):

Trick: you can hide characters you have to escape in a character range *(but it isn't always possible)*. In your case you can do it if you choose round brackets as delimiters:

```
if ( preg_match('([#--/<-@^_{-~£¬])u', '5/8', $oper) )
```

The range:

- `#--` contains `# $ % & ' ( ) * + , -`
- `<-@` contains `< = > ? @`
- `{-~` contains `{ | } ~`

*(see the ASCII table)*

Also, when you deal with multibyte strings with characters like `£` or `¬`, use the u modifier, otherwise the string and the pattern are seen as separated bytes and you may have unexpected results, example:

```
var_dump( preg_match("([¬])","¯") );
```

returns `int(1)` because `¬` is encoded with on the two bytes `C2 AC` and `¯` on the two bytes `C2 AF`. Without the u modifier, the `C2`s match.

```
var_dump( preg_match("([¬])u","¯") );
```

returns `int(0)` as expected.